# Selenium Python WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited ") - No specific error message

Tags: python, selenium

I am try to run a selenium script on firefox using python. But I receive an unclear error. I have read topics about display, but that is not my case.

**Command**

```
xvfb-run /usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/selenium-scripts/example.py >> /var/log/selenium 2>&1
```

**Script**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
import time
import datetime
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/local/firefox/firefox')
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))

display.start()
print('>> TEST START')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, timeout=60)
browser.get("http://www.vandeel.com")
print('>> TEST ENDED')

driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

**Error**

```
>> TEST START
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/selenium-scripts/example.py", line 16, in <module>
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, timeout=60)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 78, in __init__
self.binary, timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 98, in _wait_until_connectable
raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: **The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the     FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.**
```

Please advice

Comment: You should try to set more `timeout` value or remove it at all

Comment: Setting the timeout higher then default was an suggestion I read on Stackoverflow, but no difference

Comment: The Firefox Logfile is telling me the following
`XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/local/firefox/libxul.so`
Any clue?